# how to distribute load in different time in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In my application I want hit 20000 request in 10 hrs but I want distribute load in different time with different number of request means ex in 1 hrs 2000 request second hrs 3000 request third 1000 request like that how achieve this means how to separate load in diff time with diff no. of request

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is going for [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/), configuration implementing your described setup:

[image]

It's a good idea to use [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) in combination with the Throughput Shaping Timer, they can be connected via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so JMeter would be able to start extra threads if the current amount is not sufficient in order to reach/maintain the desired number of requests per second.

Both are [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer).

> N.B. although the Timer is called the Constant Throughput timer, the throughput value does not need to be constant. It can be defined in terms of a variable or function call, and the value can be changed during a test. The value can be changed in various ways:

You could set the throughput using a property or variable.
[image]

Calculate the throughput values you need at different time intervals and set the property when the time is reached.

```
props.put("currentTPM", 120)
```

You will have some work in checking the duration since the test is started.

You may create a separate thread group to control the throughput. Rename the thread group name to `TG-TM`. Set the number of threads to 1 and loop count to infinite. Set the duration of the thread group.

```
def lstThrouputInOneHour= [2000,3000,1000,5000,4000,5000]
def currentIndex=vars.get("__jm__TG-TM__idx").toInteger()

if (currentIndex <lstThrouputInOneHour.size() ) {
    def currentTPH=lstThrouputInOneHour[currentIndex]
    def currentTPM=currentTPH.intdiv(60)
    props.put("currentTPM",currentTPM.toString())
    Thread.sleep(60*60*1000)
}
```

Note: Please introduce a startup delay to other thread groups to ensure they have access to the throughput value when they start.

[image]

This solution can be extended to work with [Bean Shell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) where you could change the throughput values (JMeter properties) remotely